# Timestamp range when using Desire2Learn's REST APIs

Tags: desire2learn

What's the allowable range for discrepancies between a caller's timestamp value and the back-end service's time when making calls to Desire2Learn's Valence REST APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp threshold is narrow, but, if you are outside of the range the server will send you back the timestamp of the server. (See http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/apicall.html#disposition-and-error-handling). However, it is easiest to use a one of the libraries on the valence site as they already deal with parsing that result condition and retaining an offset in the event the Timestamp out of range error occurs.